# Import images from RSS with Feeds module without Feeds Image Grabber

Tags: 8, feeds

I'm passing all the sites from D7 to D8 and so far so good. But one of my sites gives me a couple of problems.

I was populating the RSS site in Drupal 7 using Feeds Image Grabber. Now, Feeds Image Grabber for Drupal 8 is not there. So how do I get RSS images then?

I read that maybe you can do it with the [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) module.

Any advice?

Comment: My advice would be to simply try it out yourself in some local development environment.

Answer (score 0):

RSS feeds are XML files, so you could indeed use the XML parser from [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) to extract data from it. This parser works with XPath queries. XPath is a query language to select data from a XML file. So to select the image from the RSS feed, you'll need to figure out how to select that data with the right XPath query.

It would be a good idea to learn more about XPath before using the XML parser. I think that [the XPath tutorial from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) is a good resource for this.